# Angular 7 - alternative approach for using setInterval when loading external scripts

Tags: javascript, angular

I get my header and footer of my application from external javascript files. Then I need to convert it to HTML and append it in head of HTML.

```
private loadScript() {
const dynamicScripts = [this.appConfig.config.scriptDetails.headerUrl];

for (const ds of dynamicScripts) {
  const node = document.createElement('script');
  node.src = ds;
  node.type = 'text/javascript';
  node.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
this.setUIInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (UniversalHeader) {
    const uhi = new UniversalHeader(this.uhConfig);
    const headerElements = document.getElementById('universalHeader').getElementsByTagName('a');
    this.newWindow(headerElements);        
    this.clearUIInterval();
  }
}, 100);
}
```

I am calling loadScript() in onInit(). Here I am using setInterval to check whether the script is loaded and then appending it to header. Here the issue is setInterval is firing atleast 2 times before the script loads. So, I find it not good idea to use this. Is there any alternative ways that I can achieve the same without setInterval? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onload` event of the script tag.

```js
loadScripts() {
  const dynamicScripts = [
    this.appConfig.config.scriptDetails.headerUrl
  ];

  const promises = dynamicScripts.map(url => this.loadScript(url));

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('loaded');
  });
}

loadScript(url): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    script.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };

    script.onerror = (_: any) => {
      reject('error');
    };

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}
```